# VLC plugin in .net 4.5 gives "Failed to create component 'AxHost' System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80029C4A)"

Tags: c#, vlc

We are using windows forms application in VisualStudio 2012.(.net 4.5).

We just want to use a vlc player in the design. We dragged and dropped the vlc icon after which we got the above error.

We have tried registering the axvlc.dll. It has been registered. Still this error is not going. Has anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

ya,I face it, I didn't find solution for that but,I find this statement

Version 2.x of VLC isn't managed-code-friendly, unless it's recompiled to be shared and run as an executable server, among other issues. Rather than re-building the plugin, just use a slightly older one.
 that's why,can use vlc1.1.9 or vlc 1.1.7